# Succulent Identification Needed

Tags: succulents

Purchased at a garden center without a tag. Can someone please help me with identification. It was labeled cactus on receipt, so I know it is a succulent. The "leaves" are tiny cucumber shaped. Waxy dark green. No thorns. From a 5" pot in 2 to 3 months it can grow into a nice size hanging basket.

[image: Succulent]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a "sedum rubrotinctum" for me. Have fun with your plant :)

Comment: Exactly right or otherwise called a Jelly Bean Plant. Thanks for your help.